# Gradle - Copy jars to project folder

Tags: gradle

How would I copy dependencies to somewhere in the project folder with Gradle?

I've setup SBT to do this, but I'm not sure about Gradle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your use case makes a big impact on the ways you could do this.  But, answering generically you could do something like the following to copy from a collection to a directory.

```
task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "${buildDir}/deps"
}
```

Tweak to meet your use case.  If you are trying to create a Java application take a look at the [application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).